# Remove vectors from plot of canonical variates

Tags: r

there is a vignette for canonical discriminant analysis: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/candisc/vignettes/diabetes.html

The canonical discriminant plot shows each group and a spray of vectors.
How do I remove the vectors?

I have 12 variables and the spray of vectors hides parts of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see a straightforward way to remove the vectors, but this seems to work. First the parts of the vignette that we need:

```
library(candisc)
library(heplots)
data(Diabetes)
diab.mlm <- lm(cbind(glufast, glutest, instest, sspg) ~ group, data=Diabetes)
diab.can <- candisc(diab.mlm)
```

I don't see a way to prevent the arrows from being drawn (see the manual page at `?plot.candisc`) but we can make the lines zero thick and the variable labels "":

```
plot(diab.can, ellipse=TRUE, var.lwd=0, var.labels=rep("", 4))
```

[image: Biplot]

Comment: I am happy that this answer works. I tried to understand the answer. As far as I can work out var.lwd=0 does not do anything. I can remove the arrows and leave the names using var.lwd="" if I also remove the var.labels statement. If I remove var.lwd and only use the var.labels statement I can remove both arrows and names if the number of "" in the rep statement does not match the number of variables in the model. There is an error msg. If the number matches the labels then the names are removed and only arrows printed.

Comment: Interesting. There must be differences in how different graphics devices handle this. On a Mac I get only the arrows removed with `lwd=0`, but the labels are still printed. With only `var.labels=rep("", 4)` (where 4 is the number of variables), I get only the labels removed but the arrows are present. Using both arguments gets rid of the arrows and the labels. When I try the same three versions and print to `png()` to get an output file, I get the same results.

Comment: I am on a 10-year-old DELL XPS PC running R 4.0.2 through RStudio1.3.959. I wonder how specific my outcome is to my system. Hopefully it is just a difference between PC and Mac.